# I am unable to access my desktop through my terminal with Ubuntu. It tells me no such file or directory

Tags: directory

The terminal says "No such file or directory":

[image]

Comment: There normally is no `/desktop` directory; a normal Ubuntu Desktop install may have for example a `~/Desktop/` directory; but that differs to your example. You didn't provide release though (don't forget you told it to use `desktop` in the root or `/` directory; not your user's Desktop directory - and case needs to be exact)

Comment: See [Desktop directory not opening](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104667/desktop-directory-not-opening)

Answer (score 3):

There normally is no `/desktop` directory; a normal Ubuntu Desktop install may have for example a `~/Desktop/` directory; but that differs to your example.

Don't forget you told it to use `desktop` in the root or `/` directory; not your user's Desktop directory - and case needs to be exact.

( `/desktop` and `~/Desktop` differ both in name & location )

Comment: So how would i be able to access my system desktop from within ubuntu?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're actually asking, but I can enter `ls ~/Desktop` to view the files found in `/home/guiverc/Desktop` or my `Desktop` directory (guiverc being my $USER or username). For me that's just some desktop shortcuts, and some text files.  Note I was precise with spelling (`desktop` and `Desktop` are different names as case matters!! and I specified my $HOME using the shortcut `~` which equates to $HOME or `/home/$USER`  (where $USER is my userid)